# How to solve the access permission problem for any folders in ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, scp

How to do I solve the access permission problem for any folders in Ubuntu??

I am currently trying to copy a folder from one Ubuntu to another Ubuntu machine using "scp" command.

```
scp -r foldername ipaddress_of_other_machine:directorypath
```

It shows like this:

```
scp: permission denied.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it as root. You might need to name the user at the target system, too, if it is not the same one.

`sudo scp -r <directory> <user>@<IP>:<directory>`